# How can i clear the viewstate of the page in salesforce

Tags: session, salesforce, viewstate

I am creating an application using apex where I am taking input from user. But if the user doesn't input some of the fields I want to clear the viewstate  maintained for that field.
Is this possible in salesforce?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your meaning here — if they don't fill in the fields then you don't want values in them? If they don't fill anything in then your bound variables will just contain the empty string when you process them inside of your apex controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use the transient keyword to declare instance variables that can't be saved, and shouldn't be transmitted as part of the view state for a Visualforce page.

Transient String inputfieldName;